# faster than scan() with Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

Reading ~5x10^6 numeric values into R from a text file is relatively slow on my machine (a few seconds, and I read several such files), even with `scan(..., what="numeric", nmax=5000)` or similar tricks. Could it be worthwhile to try an `Rcpp` wrapper for this sort of task (e.g. `Armadillo` has a few utilities to read text files)? 
Or would I likely be wasting my time for little to no gain in performance because of an expected interface overhead? I'm not sure what's currently limiting the speed (intrinsic machine performance, or else?) It's a task that I repeat many times a day, typically, and the file format is always the same, 1000 columns, around 5000 rows.

Here's a sample file to play with, if needed.

```
nr <- 5000
nc <- 1000

m <- matrix(round(rnorm(nr*nc),3),nr=nr)

cat(m[1, -1], "\n", file = "test.txt") # first line is shorter
write.table(m[-1, ], file = "test.txt", append=TRUE,
            row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```

**Update**: I tried `read.csv.sql` and also `load("test.txt", arma::raw_ascii)` using Armadillo and both were slower than the `scan` solution.

Comment: Try `read.csv.sql` in sqldf and see if that is any faster.  Its just one line of code.  http://sqldf.googlecode.com

Comment: I tried `system.time(b <- read.csv.sql("test.txt", header = FALSE, sep = " "))` and it was slower than `system.time(a <- scan("test.txt", what="numeric"))`. Also, I think storing the data into a matrix should be more efficient than into a `data.frame`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I highly recommend checking out `fread` in the latest version of `data.table`. The version on CRAN (1.8.6) doesn't have `fread` yet (at the time of this post) so you should be able to get it if you install from the latest source at R-forge. See [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=240).

Answer (score 5):

Please bear in mind that I'm not an R-expert but maybe the concept applies here too: usually reading binary stuff is much faster than reading text files. If your source files don't change frequently (e.g. you are running varied versions of your script/program on the same data), try to read them via scan() once and store them in a binary format (the manual has a chapter about exporting binary files). 
From there on you can modify your program to read the binary input.

@Rcpp: scan() & friends are likely to call a native implementation (like fscanf()) so writing your own file read functions via Rcpp may not provide a huge performance gain. You can still try it though (and optimize for your particular data).

Comment: re Rcpp, yes, that's my worry: implement it only to see that it performs the same as `scan()`. I was hoping someone might already have figured that one out.

Comment: I would expect it to be lots faster, but of course less general.

Answer (score 5):

Salut Baptiste,

Data Input/Output is a huge topic, so big that R comes with its own [manual on data input/output](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html).

R's basic functions can be slow because they are so very generic.  If you know your format, you can easily write yourself a faster import adapter.  If you know your dimensions too, it is even easier as you need only one memory allocation.

*Edit:*  As a first approximation, I would write a C++ ten-liner.  Open a file, read a line, break it into tokens, assign to a `vector<vector< double > >` or something like that.  Even if you use `push_back()` on individual vector elements, you should be competitive with `scan()`, methinks.

I once had a neat little `csv reader` class in C++ based on code by Brian Kernighan himself.  Fairly generic (for csv files), fairly powerful.

You can then squeeze performance as you see fit.

*Further edit:* This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415515/how-can-i-read-and-manipulate-csv-file-data-in-c) has a number of pointers for the csv reading case, and references to the Kernighan and Plauger book.

Comment: i don't know the exact dimension (well, some unix tool could find out), but 5000 is a good rough upper estimate

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you almost certainly can create something that goes faster than `read.csv`/`scan`.  However, for high performance file reading there are some existing tricks that already let you go much faster, so anything you do would be competing against those.

As Mathias alluded to, if your files don't change very often, then you can cache them by calling `save`, then restore them with `load`.  (Make sure to use `ascii = FALSE`, since reading the binary files will be quicker.)

Secondly, as Gabor mentioned, you can often get a substantial performance boost by reading your file into a database and then from that database into R.

Thirdly, you can use the [HadoopStreaming](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HadoopStreaming/index.html) package to use Hadoop's file reading capabilities.

For more thoughts in these techniques, see [Quickly reading very large tables as dataframes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r).

Comment: thanks. I think I've used all the tips from that SO thread, and no, saving the data as `.rda` or otherwise is not really an option as it's the first import that bothers me. I'll check `sqldf`, which I'd briefly considered but the syntax confused me.