# Can I read 1 big CSV file in parallel in R?

Tags: r, multithreading, csv, parallel-processing

I have a big csv file and it takes ages to read. Can I read this in parallel in R using a package like "parallel" or related? I've tried using mclapply, but it is not working.

Comment: Hi, Have you checked out this post on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060457/r-is-it-possible-to-parallelize-speed-up-the-reading-in-of-a-20-million-plus)? Also, check out `fread` in the `data.table` package. It might do what you need (but isn't in parallel).

Comment: What is `big`? Number of rows, columns, what is the size of CSV? Also, add your code, even if it is not working. I think you could use `fread` within `mclapply` and specify rownumber chunks.

Comment: I was thinking that only using one core is a slow idea. Now using fread I can do it 5% of the time. It was a CSV file of 1.2GB, and with read.csv it took about 4-5 minutes and now just 14 seconds. Thanks Richard.
I'll try to check if i can use fread() with mclapply zx, thanks.

Comment: @Ansjovis86 You can post what works best for you as an answer.

Comment: @Frank I wrote up my comment as an answer using the OP's comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based upon the comment by the OP, `fread` from the `data.table` package worked. Here's the code:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("myFile.csv")
```

In the OP's case, read in time for a 1.2GB file with `read.csv` it took about 4-5 minutes and just 14 seconds with `fread`.

**Update 29 January 2021:** It appears that `fread()` now works in parallel per a [Tweet](https://twitter.com/mattdowle/status/950924187404615681?lang=en) from the package's creator.